# Make a copy of an app

Tags: android, copy, package

Is possible to make a copy of the .apk file knowing package name?
For example, i have a package named: `com.example.package` and i want to make a copy of it in `sdcard/mydir/`. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
String package = "com.mydomain.mypackage";
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( package, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA );
String sourceDir = ai.sourceDir;
```

After that, `sourceDir` should hold the path of the `.apk` and you can copy it just as any other file. Keep in mind to wrap this in `try...catch` in case the package doesn't exist.